# Array of structure changes the contents itself

Tags: c

I am currently working on a simple code to store and display top-right triangular matrix. Well, everything was fine till I tried to input 4x4 matrix structure and gave the input. The first array of structure's (called `a`) last value changed although I did not put any code to change ANY of the values in `a`. It happens in the `mReorder()` function. Then I tried some try-and-errors find out the problem in the 3rd row of `mReorder()` function. I wonder why and how to solve it.
Here is my complete code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

//CMO fashion
typedef struct
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int val;
}term;

#define MAX_TERMS 10
term a[MAX_TERMS], b[MAX_TERMS];

void mReorder(void);

int main()
{
    int n, i, j;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n<1 || n>MAX_TERMS)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid number of rows!!");
        exit(0);
    }
    i=nCount(n);
    mRead(n,i);
    for (j=0; j<i+1; j++) printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d", a[j].col, a[j].row, a[j].val);
    mReorder();
    for (j=0; j<i+1; j++) printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d", a[j].col, a[j].row, a[j].val);
    printf("\n");
    for (j=0; j<i+1; j++) printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d", b[j].col, b[j].row, b[j].val);
    mDisplay();
    return 0;
}

void mReorder(void)
{
    int i, j, k, m=1;
    b[0].col=a[0].col;
    b[0].row=a[0].row;
    b[0].val=a[0].val;
    for(i=0; i<a[0].col; i++)
        for (j=1; j<=a[0].val; j++)
            if (a[j].row==i)
            {
                b[m].col=a[j].col;
                b[m].row=a[j].row;
                b[m].val=a[j].val;
                m++;
            }
}

void mDisplay(void)
{
    int i, j, k, m=1;
    printf("\nThe resulting matrix is:\n");
    for (i=0; i<b[0].col; i++)
    {
        //printf("\na");
        for (k=0; k<i; k++) printf("%5c", '-');
        for (j=i; j<b[0].col; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d", b[m].val);
            m++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void mRead(int n, int x)
{
    int i, j, m=1, val;
    printf("\nEnter %d elements of the matrix: \n", x);
    a[0].row=a[0].col=n;
    a[0].val=x;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &val);
            a[m].row=j;
            a[m].col=i;
            a[m].val=val;
            m++;
        }
    }

}

int nCount(int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return 1;
    return (n+nCount(n-1));
}
```

Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: You might like to read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn how to help yourself.

Comment: You can rewrite `nCount()` to avoid recursion as `int nCount(int n) { return (n + 1) * n / 2; }`.

Comment: Your question mentions a 4x4 matrix, but the code nowhere uses a 2D array.  Can you clarify what you're up to?

Comment: "*value changed although I did not put any code to change*" if such behaviour is observed in a single threaded application the reason most ever is invalid memory access. This typically happens by accessing an array out of its bounds.

Comment: You want to run your program using a memory checker like Valgrind (https://valgrind.org). For Valgrind use the (experimental) tool `--tool=exp-sgcheck`.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate enough space for 10 `term` items, but `nCount(4)` returns 10, and `nCount(5)` returns 15, etc.  If you specify a value bigger than 4, you overflow your array boundaries, leading to **undefined behaviour** — which is something to be avoided at all costs.  In practice, one of your two arrays tramples over the other, but what happens when you access the other array out of bounds is entirely up to the compiler.  It may appear to work; it may crash horribly; it may corrupt other data structures.

Nominally, since you allocate 10 elements in the arrays `a` and `b`, you should be OK with the 4x4 data, but in `mRead()`, you set `m = 1` to start with, so you end up writing to `a[10]` in the last iteration of the loop, which is outside the bounds of the array.  Remember, C arrays are indexed from 0, so an array defined as `SomeType array[N];` has elements from `array[0]` to `array[N-1]`.

Note that you can rewrite `nCount()` as a simple (non-recursive) function:

```
static inline int nCount(int n) { return (n + 1) * n / 2; }
```

(which would need to appear before it is called, of course).  Or, if you're stuck using an archaic compiler that doesn't support C99 or C11, drop the `inline` keyword.